# Reading an bytemultiarray message

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i need to read an bytemultiarray message.

I try with routings like this, but don't work with bytemultiarray.

```
void arrayCallback(const std_msgs::ByteMultiArray::ConstPtr& array)
{

    int i = 0;
    // print all the remaining numbers
    for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = array->data.begin(); it != array->data.end(); ++it)
    {
        Arr[i] = *it;
        i++;
    }

    return;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269263/reading-an-bytemultiarray-message/) by [barovehicles](https://answers.ros.org/users/31646/barovehicles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-21**:
What do you mean by

> I try with routings like this, but don't work with bytemultiarray

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I tried to create a node here using your for loop, and the problem is that CPP bytes are handled using **signed char** type, not **int**.
So, you have to do like this:

```
void arrayCallback(const std_msgs::ByteMultiArray::ConstPtr& array)
{

    int i = 0;
    // print all the remaining numbers
    for(std::vector<signed char>::const_iterator it = array->data.begin(); it != array->data.end(); ++it)
    {
        Arr[i] = *it;
        i++;
    }

    return;
}
```

There's a tutorial showing how to deal with ByteMultiArray messages, you can check it here: https://youtu.be/RMTLKf5q3Ro

---

Originally posted by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) with karma: 541 on 2017-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0